# Multiple left outer joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, left-join

I  want to implement a query in LINQ using Entity Framework with multiple Left joins but I'm getting a null reference exception, example:

```
var leftJoin = (from c in discountsList

join suc in discountsDepartmentList
on c.ListCode equals suc.ListCode

join rule in RulesList
on suc.ListCode equals rule.ListCode

join excepcion in ExceptionList
on new { suc.ListCode, rule.CategoryKey } equals new { excepcion.ListCode, excepcion.CategoryKey }
into ex from exc in ex.DefaultIfEmpty()

join prenda in prendas
on new { rule.CategoryKey , **leftExcepcion.CodigoArticulo** *-> comes with null* } equals new { prenda.CategoryKey , prenda.CodigoArticulo }

into pp
from leftPrenda in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where c.Activo == true && suc.deparmentCode== deparmentCode
select new
{

}
).Distinct();
```

i don't know how to check if leftExcepcion comes with null, so i'am getting that error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what line are you getting it on.. perhaps it's on `discountsList` what is the true scope of that.. where is it defined and or assigned.. ? have you set the necessary breakpoints and stepped through the code..?

Comment: Where does `leftExcepcion` come from?  Shouldn't that be `ex.CodigoArticulo`?

Comment: @MethodMan On the left join with Prendas **leftExcepcion.CodigoArticulo** , as the object LeftExcepcion comes with null it cannot do the relation, i am thinking to put a variable there with the product id

Comment: @juharr you're right, sorry, the problem is the same that i tried to explain before to you guys.

Comment: Thanks for the help I finished with a different solution maybe so simple, i made a store procedure, and made a different select with the function isnull.